# Get all year and months from date range in sql with or without data

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have table dbo.[sg_Attendance] with schema as shown above image.
Now using below query I am getting output with only listed data as:

```
SELECT Year(SG_PROCESS_DATE) as yearname, DATENAME(MONTH,DateAdd(MONTH, MONTH(SG_PROCESS_DATE),0) - 1) AS monthname,SUM(SG_WORKTIME) as workhour from dbo.[SG_ATTENDANCE]  where (SG_PROCESS_DATE  BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-05-01') Group By YEAR(SG_PROCESS_DATE), MONTH(SG_PROCESS_DATE)
```

My requirement is to get data for all months falling in range:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the Solution:

```
SELECT Year(SG_PROCESS_DATE) AS yearname ,DATENAME(MONTH, DateAdd(MONTH, MONTH(SG_PROCESS_DATE), 0) - 1) AS monthname ,SUM(SG_WORKTIME) AS workhour FROM innovator.[SG_ATTENDANCE] WHERE ( SG_PROCESS_DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-03-01') GROUP BY YEAR(SG_PROCESS_DATE),MONTH(SG_PROCESS_DATE)

UNION

 SELECT DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH , x.number , '2013-01-01')) as yearname, DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, '2013-01-01')) AS monthname, 0 as workhour  FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x WHERE   x.type = 'P' AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2013-01-01', '2014-03-01')

EXCEPT

SELECT Year(SG_PROCESS_DATE) AS yearname ,DATENAME(MONTH, DateAdd(MONTH, MONTH(SG_PROCESS_DATE), 0) - 1) AS monthname ,0 AS workhour FROM innovator.[SG_ATTENDANCE] WHERE ( SG_PROCESS_DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-03-01') GROUP BY YEAR(SG_PROCESS_DATE),MONTH(SG_PROCESS_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using a little trick with the `master..spt_values` table, which contains sequential number from 0 to 2047.

```
declare @months table (mm date)
declare @start date, @end date

set @start = '2013-01-01'
set @end = '2013-05-01'

insert into @months (mm)
select dateadd(day,v.number,@start) 
from master..spt_values v 
where
   v.number >= 0 and
   v.number <= DATEDIFF(day,@start,@end) and
   v.type = 'p';

SELECT Year(m.mm) as yearname, 
DATENAME(MONTH,DateAdd(MONTH, MONTH(m.mm),0) - 1) AS monthname,
SUM(SG_WORKTIME) as workhour 
from @months m
left join dbo.[SG_ATTENDANCE] a on a.SG_PROCESS_DATE = m.mm
where SG_PROCESS_DATE is null or (SG_PROCESS_DATE  BETWEEN @start AND @end) 
Group By YEAR(m.mm), MONTH(m.mm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking the expected output for a fixed date range between January and May, you can get this like

```
 SELECT yearname, monthname, SUM(workhour) AS workhour 
 FROM
 (
 SELECT Year(SG_PROCESS_DATE) AS yearname
,DATENAME(MONTH, DateAdd(MONTH, MONTH(SG_PROCESS_DATE), 0) - 1) AS monthname
,SUM(SG_WORKTIME) AS workhour
 FROM dbo.[SG_ATTENDANCE]
 WHERE (
    SG_PROCESS_DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
        AND '2013-05-01'
    )
 GROUP BY YEAR(SG_PROCESS_DATE)
,MONTH(SG_PROCESS_DATE)
 UNION ALL  
 SELECT '2013' AS yearname, 'January' AS monthname, 0 AS workhour 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2013' AS yearname, 'February' AS monthname, 0 AS workhour 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2013' AS yearname, 'March' AS monthname, 0 AS workhour 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2013' AS yearname, 'April' AS monthname, 0 AS workhour 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2013' AS yearname, 'May' AS monthname, 0 AS workhour 
)
GROUP BY yearname, monthname
```

Comment: Actually i want it to be dynamic, not fixed if range changes then output should also change..

Comment: Do you need fixed year or is it dynamic as well?

Comment: Months & Year both should be dynamic as per date range

Answer (score 0):

Same as IndoKnight , with example

`select month.monthName,strftime('%m',b.date) ,sum(b.amount) from( 
select 1 as monthNumber, 'January' as monthName union
select 2 as monthNumber, 'February' as monthName union
select 3 as monthNumber, 'March' as monthName union
select 4 as monthNumber, 'April' as monthName union
select 5 as monthNumber, 'May' as monthName union
select 6 as monthNumber, 'June' as monthName union
select 7 as monthNumber, 'July' as monthName union
select 8 as monthNumber, 'August' as monthName union
select 9 as monthNumber, 'September' as monthName union
select 10 as monthNumber, 'October' as monthName union
select 11 as monthNumber, 'November' as monthName union
select 12 as monthNumber, 'December' as monthName 
) as month 
left join bill b on month.monthNumber+' '=strftime('%m',b.date)+' '
group by monthName`

concatenate on join to convert int to varchar datatype comparision

It should work fine!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATEPROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Range_MYDLSTBind]
(
    

@FromMonth int=NULL,
@ToMonth int=NULL,
@FromYear int=NULL,
@ToYear int=NULL
    
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @FromDate DATE=NULL
        DECLARE @ToDate DATE=NULL
        SET @FromDate=DateAdd(day,0, DateAdd(month, @FromMonth - 1,DateAdd(Year, @FromYear-1900, 0)))
    SET @ToDate=DateAdd(day,-1, DateAdd(month, @ToMonth - 0,DateAdd(Year, @ToYear-1900, 0)))

SELECT DISTINCT fldMonth,fldYear, ([dbo].[GetMonthName](fldMonth)+'-'+ CONVERT(varchar,fldYear)) AS flmMonthNameY  FROM tbl_Attendance_Monthly
WHERE RDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
ORDER BY fldYear asc,fldMonth asc
        
END
```